# What does 'ng' stand for when used in software names?

Tags: naming-conventions

I've seen it a lot, like in [bwm-ng](http://www.gropp.org/?id=projects&sub=bwm-ng), or [aircrack-ng](http://aircrack-ng.org/). Does anyone know what the 'ng' part stands for when used in this way?

Comment: In the case of PHP-ng, it stands for "next generation"

Comment: "No Good" - Perhaps?!!!

Comment: @MarkBaker that might be the answer, although EdHeal might be onto something there.

Comment: Probably that's what holds true for `ng-app` in [tag:angularjs].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

-ng stands for next generation and is used to distinguish between newer or expanded implementations. Source Wikipedia!